# Why is SLiM stuck at the login screen?

Tags: virtualbox, arch-linux

I've recently installed X and SLiM but when I wanted to login it wouldn't let me. It keeps asking for username. (virtualbox)

My `/.xinitrc`:

```
DEFAULT_SESSION=ck-launch-session dbus-launch openbox-session
case $1 in
openbox)
   exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch openbox-session
xfce4)
   exec startxfce4
*)
   exec $DEFAULT_SESSION
esac
```

Log: (1st is username attempt, 2nd is root attempt)

```
slim: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections

slim: waiting for X server to shut down


slim: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections
slim: pam_authentication(): Authentication failure
```

Comment: It keeps asking for the password, or it logs in, tries to create the X-Session, then fails and throws you back at the login?

Comment: I enter my username&password but it keeps asking for them. In the logs it says "failed to authenticate"

Comment: And you are sure you are entering the correct credentials?

Comment: Yea, when I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 I can easily log into the console.

Comment: According to the wiki, login information may be wrong in the logs, so this could be another issue. Check again after correcting this, maybe : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#Login_information_with_SLiM

Comment: I've modified the file as the site said, it still keeps asking for username and password, though when I login with root is says "Failed to execute login command"

Comment: I'll try this when I get home, I use SLiM.

Comment: @SevenofNine if it still hasn't been resolved by then, we can get on IRC and I can help you through either reinstalling with the install scripts or figuring out why it isn't working properly. I do believe there are extra things you need to do to get everything to work properly in virtualbox compared to a regular install. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Arch_Linux_guests

Comment: Would you be using autologin by any chance? For me the pam authentication breaks when I do, using SLiM on GuixSD.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the archlinux wiki is a treasure trove :
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM

There is a typo in your script. All clk-launch-session should read ck-launch-session

Also, did you make .xinitrc executable ?

```
chmod +x ~/.xinitrc
```

Comment: oh sorry, that ck-clk mistype is only here, in the actual file it's alright.

Comment: but this doesnt work :[

Comment: Could you fix the logs issue as asked in my previous comment, show us the logs and fix the typo in the question ?

Comment: I tried to but I'm a bit new to Linux. I'm usually able to work out these errors but now..

Comment: From the log, it seems that authentication did not fail on user login, so it may be the window manager.

Comment: Which is the window manager?xd Xorg openbox or xfce4?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a bit of extra work to start X in virtualbox with archlinux. You can find it on the wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Arch_Linux_guests), copied and pasted below.

Installing Arch under VirtualBox is straightforward, and additions should be installed through pacman (not through "Install Guest Additions" in VirtualBox, or a mounted ISO.) Follow these instructions after doing a basic install of the X-window system found on the Beginners' Guide.

## Guest additions package

Install `virtualbox-archlinux-additions`.

## Kernel modules

Manually load the VirtualBox modules with

`# modprobe -a vboxguest vboxsf vboxvideo`

## Auto-start modules

To autostart these modules each time you boot, you can add the three modules above to the MODULES array in /etc/rc.conf.

`MODULES=(... vboxguest vboxsf vboxvideo)`

## Enable VboxClient-all

The VBoxClient contain these services(/usr/bin/VBoxClient-all) (copy/paste...) :

```
 --clipboard        start the shared clipboard service
 --display          start the display management service
 --checkhostversion start the host version notifier service
 --seamless         start the seamless windows service
```

So you can Enable VBoxClient-all to start all these services.

If you are running something that launches /etc/xdg/autostart/vboxclient.desktop, such as GNOME, then you should be ready to go. If you use .xinitrc to launch things instead, you must add

```
VBoxClient-all &
```

to your .xinitrc before launching your WM. You should now be all set, and all guest additions should work properly.

Comment: I've done that modprobe and MODULES thing but I'm not quite sure how my .xinitrc should look like. I added that line, but it made no difference.

Comment: put `VBoxClient-all &` a line above the `case $1 in`. I'll be heading home shortly and can help more when I get home.

Comment: I did that and no effect. ><

Comment: You can ask for help in #archlinux on irc.freenode.net with an IRC client, and I'll be back on to give you more information when I get home. What is the host OS?

Comment: host OS? You mean the OS that's running VirtualBox? Win7 64

Answer (score 0):

I am using OpenBSD 6.0 and I installed SLIM. I could login with root or my username. I made a huge mistake. I checked the box during logout labeled: "Save session for future logins". I could get in from then only as root but not my regular username. So through much looking around I found that I had a .cache/ folder. so I deleted all the saved sessions in ~/.cache/sessions/ and then I was able to login as my regular user again.
Of course make sure you try a logout and ensure to uncheck that box before going through with the logout. I tried it and got back in no problem and no more sessions were saved in ~/.cache/sessions/ .

I hope this helps you all.

Kevin T